# Multi-files CSV writing with Pandas MultiIndex data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multi-index

**Context**

I'm trying to write csv files of a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex built as follows :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dirty generation of fake data
timestamps = [0, 30, 60]
valuesA = [{
    0.1: 1,
    0.2: 2,
    0.3: 3}, 
    {
    0.1: 4,
    0.2: 5,
    0.3: 6},
    {
    0.1: 7,
    0.2: 8,
    0.3: 9}]
valuesB = [{
    0.1: 1.5,
    0.2: 2.5,
    0.3: 3.5}, 
    {
    0.1: 4.5,
    0.2: 5.5,
    0.3: 6.5},
    {
    0.1: 7.5,
    0.2: 8.5,
    0.3: 9.5}]

A = pd.DataFrame(valuesA ,index= [pd.Timestamp(t, unit='s') for t in timestamps])
B = pd.DataFrame(valuesB ,index= [pd.Timestamp(t, unit='s') for t in timestamps])

# The actual DataFrame I'm working with 
DATA = pd.concat([A,B],axis=1,keys=['A','B'], names=['Quantity','Position']).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print(DATA)
```

The print output looks like :

```
Position            0.1      0.2      0.3     
Quantity              A    B   A    B   A    B
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1  1.5   2  2.5   3  3.5
1970-01-01 00:00:30   4  4.5   5  5.5   6  6.5
1970-01-01 00:01:00   7  7.5   8  8.5   9  9.5
```

**Goal**

As you can see, my data is composed of two indexes : a timestamp and a position.

My goal is to write it as a sequence of csv files, one file for each timestamp, with an additional timestamp/index reference file.

For instance, the csv files, would look like :

***out_1.csv***

```
Position, A, B
0.1, 1, 1.5
0.2, 2, 2.5
0.3, 3, 3.5
```

***out_2.csv***

```
Position, A, B
0.1, 4, 4.5
0.2, 5, 5.5
0.3, 6, 6.5
```

***out_3.csv***

```
Position, A, B
0.1, 7, 7.5
0.2, 8, 8.5
0.3, 9, 9.5
```

***out_times.csv***

```
index, time
1,0
2,30
3,60
```

**Issue**

I have no problem to build the timestamp/index reference file.

Also,I achieved to  write the csv files as in the example above **but** only with non-MultiIndex data. But, I think that the method I used (transposing the DataFrame, looping on each column and using the to_csv method) is far from being the cleanest, simplest and overall best solution.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do it with MultiIndex data ?

**Additional information**

Finally, I know that the data generation example is far from being pretty, but this is not implemented as is in my code :)
I can't change the way the data should be written, neither the shape of the generated data (*DATA* in my code snippet)

Preferably, the code would support any number of "second level column indexes" (i.e. from only *A* to *A*, *B*, *C*, ... *N*). But the first level (*Position* and *Quantity* will never change)

Maybe using dask might be the solution ? I tried to understand how to work with it but no luck so far ...

Thank you for your kind help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#this is given that the timestamp is in your index

p=DATA.T.reset_index().pivot(index='Position',columns='Quantity')

filename={}
count=0
for i in DATA.index:
    p[i].to_csv("out_{}.csv".format(count))
    filename[count]=[i]
    count+=1
```

It will produce:

```
out_0.csv
out_1.csv
out_2.csv
```

with the form that you want.

then:

```
pd.DataFrame(filename).to_csv('out_times.csv')
```

to save the mapping of files and timestamp

Comment: It works perfectly as intended,
I just changed the filename dictionary in the loop to output seconds instead of timestamp in the out_times.csv : 
`filename[count]=[(i.to_numpy() - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')]` 
And transposed the filename data frame and disabling the header output !

Thanks, answer validated (y)